# Sonarqube (Version 4.5): Condition should not unconditionally evaluate to TRUE or FALSE

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar is showing error at null != textEditor.

```
TextEditor textEditor = null;

try{
   /* Initialize text editor for the current operation */
   textEditor = textEditorFactory.getCurrentEditingContext();
   if(null == textEditor){
     return;
   }
   /* doSomeOperation */
} catch (final Exception e) {
   if (null != textEditor) {
    textEditor.cancelEdit();
   }
}
```

> Error Message: Change this condition so that it does not always
>   evaluate to "false".

Comment: can you precise which language you are using ? (I am guessing Java?) and can you also precise what is the version of SonarJava Analyzer ?

Answer (score 0):

The only value `textEditor`can have in the catch block is `null`. That's because if an exception is thrown in the `try` block it can only come from the `getCurrentEditingContext()` invocation, case in which `textEditor` remains `null`.